# Trying to Convert String to Data in R, getting Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Date, value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 500

Tags: r

Date is really one of the columns and it's a `char` type; trying to make it `Date`:

```
if (!require(tidyverse)) install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(xts)
library(lubridate)

bshi <- read.csv("myfile.csv")
#Date is really one of the columns and its a "char" type, trying to make it date

bshi$Date <-mdy(bshi$Date)
str(bshi)

bshi$Date <-as.Date(bshi$Date, format =  "%m/%d/%Y")
str(bshi)

#neither work

#update:  I used colnames(<dataframe>) and found out the column name was not what I thought it was and fixed this
```

Comment: Hello, have you output `str(bshi)` before `mdy` line? Without data or preview of data it's hard to answer anything. Maybe your Date is imported as a factor, and then you should use `mdy(as.character(bshi$Date))` instead, or import with flag stringsAsFactors = FALSE.

Comment: With parsedate package, try bshi$Date <- parse_date(bshi$Date)

Comment: @Guillaume I just did and realized the column name was not what I thought it was.  Fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok then! Another good function for these tasks is `dplyr::glimpse(bshi)`, presentation is more practical. And, if you test with readr::read_csv, variable names will be printed in you console, it's practical too.